# How to write to a VARBINARY field using a stored procedure

Tags: sql

Is it possible to write a binary file (e.g. an EMF) to a VARBINARY field using a stored procedure?

Creating an example EMF

```
circle = Graphics[{Blue, Circle[{2, 0}]}, ImageSize -> Small];
Export["circle.emf", circle];
```

Reading EMF into Mathematica and writing to a Sequel VARBINARY field works using `SQLInsert`.

```
emfToBinary[file_] := Module[{inputstream, data},
   inputstream = OpenRead[file, BinaryFormat -> True];
   data = BinaryReadList[inputstream];
   Close[inputstream];
   data];

streamdata = emfToBinary["circle.emf"];

varEntityID = 123;
varFileName = "circle.emf";
varMimeType = "image/emf";
varData = SQLBinary[streamdata];

SQLInsert[conn, "media",
 {"entity_id", "file_name", "content_type", "content"},
 {varEntityID, varFileName, varMimeType, varData}]
```

> 1

However, for security I need to use a stored procedure, which I can't get to work.

```
SQLExecute[conn, StringJoin["exec AddChart ",
  varEntityID, ", '", varFileName, "', '", varMimeType, "', `1`"],
 {SQLBinary[streamdata]}]
```

> -1

```
SQLExecute[conn, StringJoin["exec AddChart ",
  varEntityID, ", '", varFileName, "', '", varMimeType, "', ",
  ExportString[streamdata, "Byte"]]]
```

> $Failed

```
SQLExecute[conn, StringJoin["exec AddChart ",
  varEntityID, ", '", varFileName, "', '", varMimeType, "', '0x010203040506'"]}]
```

> JDBC::error: Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: Is it any different if you use `ReadByteArray[inputstream]` to get a `ByteArray` instead of a list of integers?

Comment: `ReadByteArray` is available from version 11.3 on.  Its output is equivalent to `ByteArray[streamdata]`.  It doesn't look like it helps with the stored procedure.

Comment: Going to try adapting the stored procedure to accept a string and convert the string to binary inside the stored proc.